# Period-based Fast Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I have a list of events times $t_n$ in which I would like to find repeating patterns in the temporal density (how many events per second). And finally plot how likely it is to find a pattern of period $p$ to let the user decide what's worth considering.

Therefore I thought I would take a continuous approximation of the density function of my event dates with a Kernel Density Estimate (KDE). Then take its Fourier transform, and finally discretize it by period instead of frequency. (Longer [backstory here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/236881/132256). And this might also solve [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37867570/3314907) I've had.)

So, here is the KDE function and it's Fourier transform if I'm not wrong.
$$
k_h(t) = \frac{1}{Nh\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t - t_n}{h}\right)^2\right)
$$
$$
\widehat{k_h}(\nu) = \frac{e^{-2 \pi^2 h^2 \nu^2}}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-2 i \pi t_n \nu}
$$

And since I want to plot it in terms of period instead of frequency, I can define $l_h$ taking an integer argument (the period length) as follow.

$$
l_h(\lambda) = \widehat{k_h}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right) = \frac{e^{\frac{-2 \pi^2 h^2}{\lambda^2}}}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(\frac{-2 i \pi t_n}{\lambda}\right)
$$

This actually seems to work. But it's slow for a large $N$. So I was wondering if this could be accelerated in a way similar to the FFT. I can quantify the $t_n$ by rounding them to the nearest multiple of $\Delta_t$ and define $x_n$ to be the number of $t_k$ between $n\Delta_t$ and $(n+1)\Delta_t$ and approximate $l_h$ by $l'_h$ like this.

$$
l'_h(\lambda) = \frac{e^{\frac{-2 \pi^2 h^2}{\lambda^2}}}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N'-1} x_n \exp\left(\frac{-2 i \pi n}{\lambda}\right)
$$

Note that $\Delta_t$ doesn't appear in the equation because I can take it equal to 1 (e.g. 1 hour) and decide the argument of $l'_h$ is expressed in multiples of that unit ($\lambda$ hours).

If it weren't for the $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ in the complex exponential, it would definitely look like the definition of a discrete Fourier transform. I tried to apply the same technique as the [Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) but got stuck pretty fast when trying to find an periodicity in the complex exponential of the even indexed input. (Similar to $E_{k+\frac{N}{2}} = E_k$ on wikipedia.) The exponential is just not periodic in the period length.

I'm open to any suggestion, doesn't matter if $N'$ has to be prime or a power-of-two or anything else. I can always make up for that.

Comment: Potentially relevant: [Chirp $z$-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform).

Comment: I didn't know any of this before, it's a lot to take in, I may have missed something. But I'm not sure how this could help. The fact that I divide by $p$ means it's not even a Z-transform. And the Bluestein algorithm cannot be applied because it wouldn't transform to a convolution. (BTW, wikipedia talk more about the Bluestein algorithm than the Chrip Z-transform.)

Comment: I see. No, that does not seem to help, sorry.

Comment: You might want to look at the [autocorrelation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_function) instead: FFT, squared magnitude thereof (spectral power density), then inverse FFT. Of interest would be local extrema at some nonzero times.

Comment: Well, I tried to use the autocorrelation (see the two linked questions in the begining of this question). But unfortunately the result is not satisfactory. It doesn't show sharp peak at the correct period (slow to rise and slow to fade) and repeated patterns show multiple local maxima.

Comment: You should filter and downsample. For the periods of approximatively  24hours, count the number of events per hour, with a little of smoothing (an event that is almost at the middle of two hours counts half an event in each hour) and apply the short-time FFT to the obtained long signal, and detect the most powerful frequences. From this hour signal, filter a little more and down-sample $\times 12$ and apply the STFT to the obtained down-sampled signal, from which you'll detect the weeks periods, etc.  @ccorn  (note this is the same as applying a filter-bank)

Comment: and [don't forget windowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform#Discrete-time_STFT) when computing the STFT

Comment: @user1952009 This doesn't solve the problem that the Fourier transform produce values for the discrete frequencies, and not for the discrete periods. Which is exactly my problem.